# add new field in nested array

Tags: mongodb, geojson

I want to add some field into a feature collection with an object-id.
i.e to be able to add a Feature in my feature collection. The goal is to insert a new feature in a feature collection with an object-id index hashed

I tried those:

```
db.situation.update({},
{
    $addToSet: {
            "features.type" : "Feature",
            "features.id" : "test",
            "features.geometry.type": "MultiPoint"
            "features.coordinates.0":12.55388686349999,
            "features.coordinates.1":12.55388686349333,
            "features.geometry_name" : "wkb_geo",
            "features.properties.id" : NumberInt(3),
            "features.properties.vejnavn" : "Rådmandsgade",
            "features.properties.husnr" : null,
            "features.properties.betalingszone" : "Gul takstzone",
            "features.properties.tidsbegraensning" : null,
            "features.properties.ladestandertype" : "22 kW",
            "features.properties.antal_udtag" : NumberInt(2),
            "features.properties.position" : null,
            "features.properties.operatoer" : "CLEVER A/S",
            "features.properties.faerdigmeldingsdato" : null,
            "features.properties.faerdigmelding_operatoer" : null,
            "features.properties.faerdigmelding_smede" : "2020-10-19Z",
            "features.properties.bem" : null,
            "features.properties.status" : "I drift",
            "features.properties.edoc_sagsnr" : "2020-0053917",
            "features.properties.reg_dato" : null,
            "features.properties.opdateret_dato" : null
            }
}
```

I tried without quotes:

```
db.situation.updateOne({_id:ObjectId("635ad0fc5db45e7eb6444d80")},
{$addToSet: {
            features.type : "Feature",
            features.id : "test",
            features.geometry.type: "MultiPoint",
            features.coordinates.0:12.55388686349999,
            features.coordinates.1:12.55388686349333,
            features.geometry_name : "wkb_geo",
            features.properties.id : NumberInt(3),
            features.properties.vejnavn : "Rådmandsgade",
            features.properties.husnr : null,
            features.properties.betalingszone : "Gul takstzone",
            features.properties.tidsbegraensning : null,
            features.properties.ladestandertype : "22 kW",
            features.properties.antal_udtag : NumberInt(2),
            features.properties.position : null,
            features.properties.operatoer : "CLEVER A/S",
            features.properties.faerdigmeldingsdato : null,
            features.properties.faerdigmelding_operatoer : null,
            features.properties.faerdigmelding_smede : "2020-10-19Z",
            features.properties.bem : null,
            features.properties.status : "I drift",
            features.properties.edoc_sagsnr : "2020-0053917",
            features.properties.reg_dato : null,
            features.properties.opdateret_dato : null
            }
})
```

I tried with $each:

```
db.situation.updateOne({_id:ObjectId("635ad0fc5db45e7eb6444d80")},
{$addToSet: {
       features:{$each: [
            type : "Feature",
            id : "test",
            type: "MultiPoint",
           coordinates: { $each :[
                12.55388686349999,
                12.55388686349333]
            }
            geometry_name : "wkb_geo",
            properties:{$each: [
                id : NumberInt(3),
                vejnavn : "Rådmandsgade",
                husnr : null,
                betalingszone : "Gul takstzone",
                tidsbegraensning : null,
                ladestandertype : "22 kW",
                properties.antal_udtag : NumberInt(2),
                position : null,
                operatoer : "CLEVER A/S",
                faerdigmeldingsdato : null,
                faerdigmelding_operatoer : null,
                faerdigmelding_smede : "2020-10-19Z",
                bem : null,
                status : "I drift",
                edoc_sagsnr : "2020-0053917",
                reg_dato : null,
                opdateret_dato : null]}
            ]}}
})
```

I used $ for nested fields:

```
db.situation.updateOne({_id:ObjectId("635ad0fc5db45e7eb6444d80")},
{$addToSet: {
       features:{
            features.type : "Feature",
            features.id : "test",
            features.$.geometry:{
                type: "MultiPoint",
                    coordinates: {
                        12.55388686349999,
                        12.55388686349333
                }
            features.geometry_name : "wkb_geo",
            features.$.properties:{
                id : NumberInt(3),
                vejnavn : "Rådmandsgade",
                husnr : null,
                betalingszone : "Gul takstzone",
                tidsbegraensning : null,
                ladestandertype : "22 kW",
                properties.antal_udtag : NumberInt(2),
                position : null,
                operatoer : "CLEVER A/S",
                faerdigmeldingsdato : null,
                faerdigmelding_operatoer : null,
                faerdigmelding_smede : "2020-10-19Z",
                bem : null,
                status : "I drift",
                edoc_sagsnr : "2020-0053917",
                reg_dato : null,
                opdateret_dato : null]
               }
            ]}}
})
```

Comment: Are you sure [`"$addToSet"`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) is the `update` operator you want to use here?

Comment: I just want to add a new feature inside the featurecollection, I don't know what method is the best

Comment: Is `"features"` an array already present in the document?

Comment: yes features is an array present in the document

Comment: Are you trying to add one object (with several fields) to the `"features"` array?